# Counting shared words between strings in two columns of a data frame

Tags: r

I have two columns in a table containing genelists as characters, e.g.

```
x <- data.frame("Patient" = 1:3, "Genes1" = c("EGFR; TP53; BRCA1","CDK1; CD274; PARP1","MAP2K1; MAP2K2; PIK3CA"), "Genes2" = c("EGFR; TP53; MAP2K1; VEGF", NA,"MAP2K1; MTOR"))
```

I wish to create a new column with a count of the number of shared genes between the other columns for the respective row.  I am attempting to do this in R by splitting the characters into a list and counting shared elements:

```
x <- x %>% mutate(Count = length(intersect(strsplit(Genes1, "; ")[[1]], strsplit(Genes2, "; ")[[1]])))
```

or

```
x$Count1 <- length(intersect(strsplit(x$Genes1, "; ")[[1]], strsplit(x$Genes2, "; ")[[1]]))
```

but this is returning "2" for every row rather than the row specific result I want, which would be

```
 x <- data.frame("Patient" = 1:3, "Genes1" = c("EGFR; TP53; BRCA1","CDK1; CD274; PARP1","MAP2K1; MAP2K2; PIK3CA"), "Genes2" = c("EGFR; TP53; MAP2K1; VEGF", NA,"MAP2K1; MTOR"), Count = c(2,0,1))
```

Any pointers?

Comment: A base R solution similar to the accepted answer would be `x$Count <- lengths(mapply(intersect, strsplit(x$Genes1, "; "), strsplit(x$Genes2, "; ")))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An option is to split the columns with `strsplit`, do a corresponding `list` element check with `map2` with `intersect` and get the `lengths` of the `intersect`ing elements

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
x %>% 
   mutate(Count = lengths(map2(strsplit(Genes1, ";\\s*"), 
                               strsplit(Genes2, ";\\s*"), intersect)))
```